# Vidyo iOS integrated with Cordova ionic - Close (disconnect) keeps video active in background

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, vidyo

We made an effort to write a ionic Cordova plugin bridge for the Vidyo SDK so that we can integrate this into our ionic project. This works all well on Android, but on iOS we face one issue.

When we close (disconnect) a call and the Vidyo SDK overlay gets closed and user returns to the ionic app, however in the background the video/audio is still active (even when disconnected). Leaving the app shows a glowing red status bar on the top, indicating an active call. 
How can we properly close the vidyo overlay? Disconnect does not seem enough.
Thanks

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Disconnect isn't enough in your case.
You should use vc?.Disable() after the call has been disconnected. This will release all used resources (camera, mic, speaker).
But make sure that you call Disable and/or VCConnectorPkg.uninitialize() only after you recieved OnDisconnected callback.

Btw, here is the sample from Vidyo:
https://github.com/Vidyo/VidyoIOCordovaPlugin